# Javascript/JQuery Nested if statements not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhyhLctw/) demonstrating problem (pretty hard to see with the corner box)

I have 4 elements that are linked to each button. When the button corresponding with the section is pressed, it should check that none of the other 3 elements are visible. If another section is visible, it should slide it up before sliding down the desired section.

I thought the best way to do this was nested if statements (if b is visible then if c is visible and so on). At the moment, it works for the first 2 elements, this being because the first if statement corresponds to each of them. However for the others, it's as if it doesn't even get past the first statement and just slides down the section anyway, resulting in multiple sections being open.

Am i using nested if statements incorrectly or is it something that isn't compatible? I don't know if it would be better to hide the sections using jquery instead of css, but i assumed it would work regardless. If I've missed anything out, feel free to ask.

Thanks

---

(Javascript Code)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#web-design").click(function(){
    if ($("#graphic-design-slide").css("visibility") == "hidden") {
        if ($("#branding-slide").css("visibility") == "hidden") {
            if ($("#film-production-slide").css("visibility") == "hidden") {
                $("#web-design-slide").slideDown();
            } else {
                $("#film-production-slide").slideUp();
                $("#web-design-slide").slideDown();
            }
        } else {
            $("#branding-slide").slideUp();
            $("#web-design-slide").slideDown();
        }
    } else {
        $("#graphic-design-slide").slideUp();
        $("#web-design-slide").slideDown();
    }
});

$("#graphic-design").click(function(){
   if ($("#web-design-slide").css("visibility") == "hidden") {
        if ($("#branding-slide").css("visibility") == "hidden") {
            if ($("#film-production-slide").css("visibility") == "hidden") {
                $("#graphic-design-slide").slideDown();
            } else {
                $("#film-production-slide").slideUp();
                $("#graphic-design-slide").slideDown();
            }
        } else {
            $("#branding-slide").slideUp();
            $("#graphic-design-slide").slideDown();
        }
    } else {
        $("#web-design-slide").slideUp();
        $("#graphic-design-slide").slideDown();
    }

});

$("#branding").click(function(){
    if ($("#web-design-slide").css("visibility") == "hidden") {
        if ($("#graphic-design-slide").css("visibility") == "hidden") {
            if ($("#film-production-slide").css("visibility") == "hidden") {
                $("#branding-slide").slideDown();
            } else {
                $("#film-production-slide").slideUp();
                $("#branding-slide").slideDown();
            }
        } else {
            $("#graphic-design-slide").slideUp();
            $("#branding-slide").slideDown();
        }
    } else {
        $("#web-design-slide").slideUp();
        $("#branding-slide").slideDown();
    }
});

$("#film-production").click(function(){
    if ($("#web-design-slide").css("visibility") == "hidden") {
        if ($("#graphic-design-slide").css("visibility") == "hidden") {
            if ($("#branding-slide").css("visibility") == "hidden") {
                $("#film-production-slide").slideDown();
            } else {
                $("#branding-slide").slideUp();
                $("#film-production-slide").slideDown();
            }
        } else {
            $("#graphic-design-slide").slideUp();
            $("#film-production-slide").slideDown();
        }
    } else {
        $("#web-design-slide").slideUp();
        $("#film-production-slide").slideDown();
    }
});

$("#contactFormTitle").click(function(){
    if ($("#contactFormArea").css("visibility") == "hidden") {
        $("#contactFormArea").slideDown();
    } else {
        $("#contactFormArea").slideUp();
    }
}); 

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `slider` class (or any other) to each container and link the container with button using `data` attribute:

Button:

```
<button class="serviceButton displayed" data-id="#web-design-slide">Find Out More!</button>
```

Container:

```
<div class="slider serviceSliderWebDesign" id="web-design-slide">
   ...
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(".serviceButton").click(function(){
    // grab the container id from data-id attribute of the button:
    var el_id = $(this).data('id');
    $('.slider:not('+el_id+')').slideUp('slow', function(){
        $(el_id).slideDown();
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pjnztcgr/)

---

If you want to also toggle container on click, use [**`slideToggle()`**](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/):

```
$(".serviceButton").click(function () {
    var el_id = $(this).data('id');
    $('.slider:not(' + el_id + ')').slideUp();
    $(el_id).slideToggle();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pjnztcgr/1/)

Comment: This works great thanks. Just an added question, if i wanted it to slideUp the current slide if it was already open (click once to slide down / another time to slide back up), how would i go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Your should add class to your container and before showing the desired container, hide all container with that class.

***Example***

```
<div class="accordion">
  Content
</div>
<div class="accordion">
  Content
</div>
<div class="accordion">
  Content
</div>

$('.accordion').click(function() {
  $('.accordion').slideUp();
  $(this).slideDown();
});
```

***Your example***

```
$("#web-design").click(function(){
    $(".div-to-hide").slideUp();
    $("#web-design-slide").slideDown();
});

$("#graphic-design").click(function(){
    $(".div-to-hide").slideUp();
    $("#graphic-design-slide").slideDown();
});


<div class = "serviceSliderFilmProduction div-to-hide" id = "film-production-slide">
```

***div-to-hide*** class is added to your container

Comment: I understand where you're going with this, but how would this work if i'm not actually pressing the containers. Currently, it works by pressing a button that hides / displays the necessary containers. And when i try to slideUp() .accordion, it stops the slidedown() action from happening.